# Tags that are a technology and a pattern

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag [snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake)is being used by a vendor (by the same name) for their data warehouse offering. The usage guidance reflects this, but the tag wiki is about the snowflake data design pattern. This mismatch between the usage guidance and the wiki seems messy.

What are the best practices on designing a tag wiki (or tag naming) when it can be applied to both a product and a design pattern?

Answer (score 2):

There is already a [snowflake-datawarehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-datawarehouse) tag, so all the questions about the data warehouse should be retagged to use that. Next we should request a moderator to rename [snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake) to [snowflake-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-pattern), and then we should edit the tag wiki/excerpt to remove usage guidance that refers to the data warehouse offering.

There's also a [snowflake-connector-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-connector-python) with no usage guidance that we have to figure out.

Because you have less than 20k reputation, note that any edits you might make to new or existing tag wikis will need to be approved by other users.